# Latitude - Longitude bounds from GeoTIFF info

Tags: geotiff-tiff, latitude-longitude

here's the content of a GSFC-generated GOES TIFF image:

```
GOES 13 Imager frame  66 at UTC 12:45:53.520 day 312 of 2013
Vis pixels :   9061, 22912    lines :   2845, 10152
Vis Lon    : 999999,-23.1566 Lat   : 999999,-20.9474
Imager ch3:count(0,1023) => [(modea-0)/1]^1 =Uchar> (255,69)
(xscale,yscale) => (0.190476,0.333333)
Vis pixels:  3650,  28850 lines:  2250,  14250
(xstride,ystride) => (21,12)
IMC status:      1
nadir pixel,line:  15352,  8050
Ref lon,d,lat,yaw:  -74.99990305,   42164.17478,         0,         0
Attitude roll,pitch,yaw:          0,         0,         010491171
```

The TIFF file is here: http://goes.gsfc.nasa.gov/goeseast-lzw/overview/ir3/latest.tif

¿How can I get/calculate the geographic bounds from this information or from the GeoTIFF file itself?

¿Can I do this somehow opening the file in QGIS?  Do I have to develop some script?

I only need to do this one time.

Thanks to anybody dedicating his/her time on answering this!

Answer (score 1):

Sure,

Firstly, open it in QGIS, and then in the menu at the top go to Raster->Miscellaneous->Information.

Select the layer in the "Input-file" drop-down box (if it's not already there) then press OK, and it will create a load of text relating to information about the layer in a box called "Raster Info".

If you scroll down this text, you will get to a line that says "Corner Coordinates", the following 4 lines look like this:

```
Upper Right ( 5486108.843, 5015161.555) ( 14d49'22.49"E, 45d16'51.06"N)
```

and describe the coordinates of each corner (the geographic bounds) (in my example, given as both projected and geographic coordinates).

Is that what you're after?

Note: if you can't see any part of Raster->Miscellaneous->Information in the menu, go to Plugins->Manage and Install Plugins, and make sure that the box next to "GDAL Tools" is ticked, this will make it appear

Comment: Hi thx I already had used gdalinfo on the tif file and got the following corner coordinates: upper left:(0,0) Lower left:(0,1000) Upper Right:(1200,0) Lower Right:(1200,1000)... but those are not the geographic coordinates I'm looking for, how would you calculate the real coordinates? Do you also have to guess and provide the projection... It's for a groundoverlay in Google Maps.

Comment: OK, did the file come with a *.tfw file alongside it? Is that still stored in the same directory?

Comment: (I'm assuming that GDALINFO is listing the "Origin" as 0,0 as well?)

Comment: gdalinfo returned also Center(600,500). And there is no .tfw file, just latest.tif.  I believe there must be a formula to convert the tif's coordinates to geographic coordinates, right?

Comment: it sounds like the file is not georeferenced, do you have any data you could georeference it against? if you downloaded it, it might be worth re-downloading to see if you can find . *.TFW file. if the TFW file was in the same directory, then GDAL and other GIS' would  georeference it for you automatically based upon the contents of that file.

Answer (score 0):

From the [**GOES FAQ**](http://goes.gsfc.nasa.gov/text/#tiffcomment):

> The 3rd line lists the longitude and latitude of the northwest and
>   southeast corners of the original frame, with all 9's when the corner
>   is in outer space.

In your case:

```
Vis Lon    : 999999,-61.9663 Lat   : 999999,13.9346
```

means:

- **Longitude of the northwest corner:** 999999 (the corner is in outer
  space)
- **Longitude of the southeast corner:** -61.9663
- **Latitude of the northwest corner:** 999999 (the corner is in outer space)
- **Latitude of the southeast corner:** 13.9346